# React Native - onLayout not being called when running on an iPhone

Tags: react-native

React native beginner here. This is my app.js screen. It seems to work okay if I run it in an Android simulator. However, if I run it on an iPhone using the Expo go app it immediately crashes upon loading. I have determined that the onLayoutRootView doesn't get called when running on the iPhone. Spent way to long trying to fix this so any help much appreciated

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import SideStack from './routes/sideStack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './redux/store'
import { SetUser } from './redux/user';

export default function App() {

const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 async function prepare() {
  try {
    await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    Store.dispatch(SetUser())
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  } finally {
    setAppIsReady(true);
  }
}

prepare();
}, []);

const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {

  console.log("Doesn't get here")

    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

if (!appIsReady) {
  return null;
}

return (
<Provider store={Store}>
<View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <SideStack />
  </NavigationContainer>
  </View>
   </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am guessing the double `on` is a typo here? Also it's better to call `SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()` in the root of your app instead of in your component. The trigger then might come too late, when the splash screen is already hidden.

Comment: @Kipnoedels Yes it was a typo, sadly not the cause of my issue :-( When you say call it in the root, where would that be? Sorry, I'm new at this

Comment: Just under your imports. If you take a look at the docs you can see how they do it: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/